# In-place modification of a python list when condition is met

Tags: python

I've got a list of numbers, and I also compute all possible combinations of two of this list. What I want to do is check whether the sum of the first combination is less than 5, and if so, choose a random number out of the 2 from the combination, remove that number from the initial list and re-calculate the combinations, etc.

```
import itertools
import random

numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

all_combos = list(itertools.combinations(numbers, 2))

for combo in all_combos:
    if combo[0] + combo[1] < 5:
        choice = random.choice([combo[0],combo[1]])
        numbers.remove(choice)
```

The error I get

```
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Initially I thought it was the inplace changing of the list in combination with the for loop that caused this, so I also tried implementing a while loop, but it always ends up being an infinite loop since I can't seem to find the correct condition for it.

Comment: Since it is a random choice, if you run it a few more times you will encounter the error I described.

Comment: `and re-calculate the combinations`. You aren't actually doing this. You are calculating the combinations once.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to actually recalculate the combinations as you say in the question, you need to put that `itertools.combinations` call somewhere in the loop and regenerate it after mutating `numbers`.

One way would be to use a while loop and only break once you've made it through the combinations without finding more pairs that meet your criteria:

```
import itertools
import random

numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]


while True:    
    all_combos = itertools.combinations(numbers, 2)
    try:
        pair = next(p for p in all_combos if sum(p) < 5)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    choice = random.choice(pair)
    numbers.remove(choice)
```

This will make a small difference in the statistics of the choices because removing `2` in the first iteration removes all possibility of removing `3` in the pair `(2, 3)` later where simply removing it from `numbers` and continuing leaves that choice in the combinations. This means your odds of having `3` left in your number list are higher than the other way of doing this.

Comment: I like the emphasis on how this changes the distribution of the result.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is random, you may end up trying to remove a number already removed.

Just wrap in a `try / except`:

```
    try:
        numbers.remove(choice)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Or, ask permission:

```
    if choice in numbers: 
        numbers.remove(choice)
```

Comment: You will end up stepping through a bunch of options that contain the removed number if you do that.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you may choose the same number more than once, causing the error. You could put the numbers you want to remove in a set, which removes duplicates, and do the remove later.

```
import itertools
import random

numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

all_combos = list(itertools.combinations(numbers, 2))

remove_this = {}
for combo in all_combos:
    if combo[0] + combo[1] < 5:
        choice = random.choice([combo[0],combo[1]])
        remove_this.add(choice)
for choice in remove_this:
    numbers.remove(choice)
```

That can be reduced to

```
remove_this = {random.choice(combo)
        for combo in itertools.combinations(numbers, 2)
        if sum(combo) < 5}
for choice in remove_this:
    numbers.remove(choice)
print(numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now, you are removing a number from `numbers` but not updating `all_combos`. That means the number will almost certainly show up in `all_combos` again, but be missing from `numbers`. You do not need to regenerate all possible combinations every time you remove a number, but you do need to filter `all_combos` and adjust your position accordingly. A simple method for doing so is to maintain a list of booleans that you update every time you discard a number:

```
from itertools import combinations
from random import choice

numbers = list(range(1, 11))

all_combos = list(combinations(numbers, 2))

valid = [True] * len(all_combos)
for i, combo in enumerate(all_combos):
    if not valid[i]: continue
    if sum(combo) < 5:
        c = random.choice(combo)
        valid[i + 1:] = (valid[j] and c not in all_combos[j] for j in range(i + 1, len(all_combos)))
```

This algorithm is much cheaper than regenerating the entire list of combinations at every step since it just skips invalidated combos. You could further reduce the complexity from `O(n2)` (because you revisit the entire tail of `all_combos` at each step) by using a `set` to keep track of discarded elements and deciding which ones to skip on the fly. This will be `O(n2)` because set lookup is ostensibly `O(1)`:

```
from itertools import combinations
from random import choice

numbers = list(range(1, 11))

all_combos = list(combinations(numbers, 2))

dropped = set()
for i, combo in enumerate(all_combos):
    if any(x in dropped for x in dropped): continue
    if sum(combo) < 5:
        dropped.add(random.choice(combo))
```